# external validation, cox regression, insignificant variables, significant model

Tags: survival, cox-model

I wanted to perform an external validation of The Score prediciting survival.

SPSS v. 26.
I used Cox regression. When I put the same variables as proposed two of them were > 0.05, although the model itself was < 0.05.

May I say that The Score cannot be used on my patients until modified or should I proceed with these variables?

Comment: Please provide more details about your situation: how many cases, how many events (e.g., recurrences or deaths) in train and test sets, how many predictors in your model, whether standard clinical characteristics were included along with your "Score," etc. If you are interested in prediction there is no need to remove individual predictors that don't meet a p < 0.05 criterion, but without a lot more information it will be hard to say whether that's wise in your case. Please add that information by editing the question, as comments are often overlooked and can sometimes be lost.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It is all I need. Browsing through your wonderful project brought me to the paper which told me where i was entrapped Royston P, Altman DG. External validation of a Cox prognostic model: principles and methods. BMC Med Res Methodol. 2013 Mar 6;13:33. doi: 10.1186/1471-2288-13-33. PMID: 23496923; PMCID: PMC3667097.